# Target another ID attribute when page reload

Tags: javascript, html

How can I target another ID when the page reloads? For below example, from another page it will bring parameter and redirects to this page, if the parameter is "EM" the page will auto target the module "eMOTOR" .

https://test.e-cover.com.my/shk/test/test2.jsp

Answer (score 0):

You can put the parameter in query parameter eg:`https://test.e-cover.com.my/shk/test/test2.jsp?target=EM`. After that there are 2 options: (1) read it in the servlet and render class `active` to the tab or (2) do the same thing using [js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

**EDIT**

There may be a better way if you check the library doc, but you definitely can select the tab with jquery:

```
$('.search-box li').removeClass('active')
$('.search-box li').eq(1).addClass('active') // index 1 = eMOTOR
```

Of course it would be better if you add an id or class to the `li`, eg `emotor`:

```
$('.search-box li').removeClass('active')
$('.search-box li.emotor').addClass('active')
```

Comment: i can get parameter , just have no idea how to use javascript to target the eMotor ID.. i tried the html dom target attribute, but failed..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common class for example `button` and to get the id use `e.target.id` . To reload the url use `window.location.replace`

```
 $('.button').on('click', function(e){
  window.location.replace("https://test.e-cover.com.my/shk/test/test2.jsp?target="+e.target.id);
  //alert(e.target.id);    
});
```

Comment: i can get parameter , just have no idea how to use javascript to target the eMotor ID when the page is reload..

Comment: See this [How to remain in the tab selected after reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935169/how-to-remain-in-the-tab-selected-after-reloading-the-page)